# How to change Ubuntu Server Login message

Tags: ssh, login

I would like to change the first login message when I SSH to the server. Currently I use putty to SSH to my Ubuntu Server 16.04 and the first login page displays Login as: This is where I input my username.

I would like to add a message for my other users here with specific information about this server.

I know how to modify and the motd. The motd displays after login. i want to change what is displayed at the SSH login page.

Comment: That post is about post SSH login. I want to change what is displayed at the SSH login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Banner` directive of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` takes a filename as argument and shows the file content before user login, precisely before password prompt.

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and append:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "Banner /path/to/file.txt" >>/etc/ssh/sshd_config'
```

change the filename to meet your need. Or use your preferred editor to edit the file.

Don't forget to restart the `ssh` daemon:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

On `systemd`:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about the Banner on the other thread. You are correct and answered my question.